# Distribute a number among n number of rows equally in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we distribute a number n among x number of rows in result set.

```
Create Table tmp (
AccPrd datetime not null,
DistributedValue decimal(18,1)  
)
```

For example I have
@n decimal(18,1)= 7 and
x = 4 (number of rows in result set)

tmp table has 4 rows in it and when I distribute the 7 among this rows by doing Round(@n/x,1,1) = 1.7

[image]

In above image when I total this up I'm getting 6.8 and .2 is lost during distribution.

I saw this is something similar like a account problem.
One of the solution I came up with is finding the difference and adding that difference to first row.

But I wanted to see if there is a better approach to distribute this remainder evenly among rows.

In above example for 0.2 remainder, as I can not distribute it among all 4 rows. I want to add 0.1 for 1st and 2nd row, that totals up to 7 when all rows are added.

DistributedValue is one decimal place. So, the least number it can be .1 when doing distribution

**Current solution I had:**

[image]

**Expecting:**

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The below answer is very product specific.)

Comment: RDBMS in SQL Server @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

I used loop to get the solution I need

Add row number to tmp table and find difference in (Actual value - avg totals) ie., in my above example
Actual value is @n = 7 and avg totals = 6.8 => 7- 6.8 = 0.2(difference)

```
    SET @itr = select Count(*) from tmp
    WHILE @difference > 0
    BEGIN
        Update #tmp DistributedValue = DistributedValue + 0.1
        Where RowNo = @itr

        SET @itr = @itr - 1
        SET @DistributedValue = @DistributedValue - 0.1
        IF @DistributedValue <> 0 And @itr = 1 -- reset the @itr to last row number
            BEGIN
                SET @itr = select Count(*) from tmp
            END
    END
```

Result look like below (note: added the difference from bottom row)

[image]